# Button automatically sizes to 0px x 0px

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table, imagebutton

I'm try to do a table with a ImageButton in one cell.

My table is implemented like this:

```
<table class="features-table">
                <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <td></td>
                               <td>1</td>
                               <td>2</td>
                               <td>3</td>
                               <td>4</td>
                               <td>5</td>
                               <td>6</td>
                               <td>7</td>
                               <td>8</td>
                               <td>9</td>
                               <td>10</td>
                               <td>1</td>
                           </tr>
                </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                        </tfoot>
                <tbody>
            <div id="IDDIV" runat="server"></div>
                </tbody></table>
```

I'm filling my table by adding a html-string to the div. This string is generated with a method like this:

```
    private string buildHtmlTableString(List<Week> w)
    {
        string result = "";
        foreach (Week element in w)
        {
            string s = "<tr>" +
                        "<td> Week " + element.weekNumber + 
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.1 + " €</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.2 + " €</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.3 + " €</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.4 + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.5 + " €</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.6+ "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.7 +" €</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.8 + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.9 + " €</td>" +
                        "<td>" + element.10 + " €</td>" +
                        "<td>" + "<asp:ImageButton runat=\"server\" ID=\"" + element.1 + "\" Height=\"20px\" Width=\"20px\" OnClick=\"test_Click\" ImageUrl=\"~/detail.ico.ico\"></asp:ImageButton></td>" +
                        "</tr>";
            result = result + s;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The style of the table:

```
#main
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 160px auto 0 auto;
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #adaa9f;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #9c9c9c;
}

/*Features table------------------------------------------------------------*/
.features-table
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  background: #fafafa;  
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eaeaea, #fff); /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,center bottom,center top,from(#fff),color-stop(0.5, #eaeaea),to(#fff)); 
}

.features-table td
{
  border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Body*/
.features-table tbody td
{
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
  width: 150px;
}

.features-table tbody td:first-child
{
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
}


.features-table td:nth-child(1)
{
  background: #e7f3d4;  
  background: rgba(179,0,0,0.3);
}

/*Header*/
.features-table thead td
{
  background: rgba(144,144,144,0.15);
  font: bold 12px 'trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans', Arial;  
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px; 
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; 
}

.features-table thead td:first-child
{
  border-top: none;
}

/*Footer*/
.features-table tfoot td
{
  font: bold 1.4em Georgia;  
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.features-table tfoot td:first-child
{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

My Problem is that those Image buttons aren't shown in the table. If I analyse the html code of my page with chrome I can see that the labels are generated, but, and I have no idea why, my button is sized 0px x 0px. Maybe anyone of you knows what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually dont know the Problem, but you could do a little workaround until someone else has a solution.

Dont add a button, just add a piczure and link it to your page with a dynamically parameter. Like a week number in your case. In your Linked file you just have to analyze the paramenter and voila you know wich tablecoulom is pressed.

Intrested to see other solutions!
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `div` in `table` without keeping its structure. As you can see in firebug your `div` is ignored by `table` and located inside `body`. The structure should be like this.

```
<table class="features-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="IDDIV" runat="server"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Couldn't test your code without image, so not sure if this will solve the problem, but I guess you should start from this, this will solve much problems for you

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:ImageButton>` is an ASP.NET server-side control... and as such it needs to be created by ASP.NET.

You cannot just create a string using `<asp:ImageButton>` and expect the system to recognise it as a control.  My guess is that when you look at the rendered HTML, you're actually seeing `<asp:ImageButton>` instead of what an actual control would produce (which would be `<input type="image">`).

In order to do what you want, you need to generate a series of controls, first using a `<asp:Literal>` for the normal text, and then `<asp:ImageButton>` for buttons.

Instead of using `<div>` use a `<asp:PlaceHolder>`.

Then build up your controls roughly like this...

```
private void buildHtmlTableString(List<Week> w)
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (Week element in w)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<td> Week {0}</td>", element.weekNumber);
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0} €</td>", element.1);
        ...
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0} €</td>", element.10);
        sb.Append("<td>");
        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal(sb.ToString()));
        sb.Length = 0;

        var imgBtn = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton
        {
            ID = element.1.ToString(),
            Width = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(20),
            Height = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(20),
            ImageUrl = @"~/detail.ico"
        };
        imgBtn.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(text_Click);
        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(imgBtn);
        sb.Length = 0;

        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal("</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

---

Also, having a `<div>` within the `<tbody>` is invalid HTML, but the above removes that anyway